# Get FQDN of workstation client application is running on

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'd like to know the way to get FQDN of workstation client application is running on. I've tried `HOST_NAME()`, but it returns only the left part.
I've found out, that `sys.dm_exec_connections` is rather useful, but there is only client's workstation IP address, no FQDN.

Comment: How would you get the FQDN of an application running on a client from SQL Server?  Are you saying you want to use the client's connection to SQL Server to determine their FQDN?

Comment: Be aware that the `HOST_NAME()` can also return whatever was is specified in the connection string. You did not mention why you need the FQDN but you could build the connection string in the app with the host name connection string keyword (which varies by API) so that `HOST_NAME()` returns that value.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thank you for this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess, [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58856522/get-fqdn-of-workstation-client-application-is-running-on#comment103986049_58856522)'s the answer.

> Be aware that the HOST_NAME() can also return whatever was is specified in the connection string. You did not mention why you need the FQDN but you could build the connection string in the app with the host name connection string keyword (which varies by API) so that HOST_NAME() returns that value.

TY, Dan Guzman